# Can a Docker container with a Linux base image run in Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, docker, containers

I do not have much experience with Docker and would really appreciate some guidance on a concern of mine.
I wish to create a containerized ML Model that takes in some data from a local file, runs some analysis and returns results. The system that this container runs on would be a Windows PC. My concerns are:

1. If I create a Linux based image for this ML model app, will it work on the windows pc ? Would installing WSL-2 facilitate it?
2. Even if it does, is the version of Windows important in this case ?

I have not actually tried this out because I wanted some initial advice on what is possible. Thank you in advance for any help and please do tell me if additional info is required!

Comment: A container uses the kernel of the host and therefore a Linux container can't run on Windows - and vice versa. WSL allows you to run Linux images on Windows by running a Linux VM behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run linux based containers with [Docker for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/windows-install/) with WSL 2 enabled.

Docker Desktop usually automatically installs/enables WSL on install. If not, you can setup WSL2 manually: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install